# How to call a function into a file

Tags: python, function, directory-structure

I'm trying to import a function that I have a file in another folder with this structure:

```
Data_Analytics
|---Src
|    ---__init.py__
|    ---DEA_functions.py
|    ---importing_modules.py
|---Data Exploratory Analysis
|    ----File.ipynb
```

So, from File.ipynb (from now I'm working in notebook) I want to call a function that I have in the file DEA_functions.py. To do that I typed:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, "../")
from Src.Importing_modules import *
import Src.DEA_functions as DEA
```

No errors during the importing process but when I want to call the function I got this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'Src.DEA_functions' has no attribute 'getIndexes'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-534dff78ff93> in <module>
      4 
      5 #There is a negative value that we want to delete
----> 6 DEA.getIndexes(df,df['Y3'].min())
      7 df['Y3'].min()
      8 df['Y3'].iloc[14289]=0

AttributeError: module 'Src.DEA_functions' has no attribute 'getIndexes'e
```

And the function is defined in the file, this way:

```
def getIndexes(dfObj, value):
''' Get index positions of value in dataframe i.e. dfObj.'''
listOfPos = list()
# Get bool dataframe with True at positions where the given value exists
result = dfObj.isin([value])
# Get list of columns that contains the value
seriesObj = result.any()
columnNames = list(seriesObj[seriesObj == True].index)
# Iterate over list of columns and fetch the rows indexes where value exists
for col in columnNames:
    rows = list(result[col][result[col] == True].index)
    for row in rows:
        listOfPos.append((row, col))
# Return a list of tuples indicating the positions of value in the dataframe
return listOfPos
```

I hope I made myself clear but if not do not hesitate to question whatever you need. I just want to use the functions I have defined in my file DEA_functions.py into my File.ipynb

Thank you!

Comment: Does everything work as expected if the scripts and notebook are in the same directory? Specifically, looks like you're referring to the wrong function, not that the import failed

Comment: Yes, it worked in the same folder, I decided to move to a folder to structure my code and I got this error

Comment: Looks like I am not allowed to put the name in capital letters, so dea works fine having DEA_functions.py in Src folder, looks like it is solved. Thank you @OneCricketeer for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, I assigned DEA as the shortname for calling my functions. Looks like I had to use lower case letter. So:

```
import Src.DEA_funct as dea
```